# How can I import pajek .paj files into igraph for R?

Tags: r, graph, import, igraph, sna

[This tutorial](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/igraphbook/igraphbook-foreign.html) and the [package documentation](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/read.graph.html) describe how to do it for pajek files of the .net format, but I need to import .paj files.  I don't expect there is code that will import all .paj files, but perhaps someone has code that will work for some simpler ones that I could then modify for my purposes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with the following approach:

1. Read the whole file using `readLines()`.
2. Drop the comment lines, lines that start with '`%`'.
3. Cut the lines into pieces, lines that start with a star ('`*`') mark the start of a new piece.
4. Inspect each piece in the order they appear and convert them into the appropriate R data structure.

In Step 4 you may have several types of pieces:

- `*Network` is the start of a network.
- `*Vertices` defines vertices and belongs to the previous network.
- `*Edges` defines undirected edges, it belongs to the previous network.
- `*Arcs` defines directed edges, it belongs to the previous network.
- `*Partition` is the start of a partition.
- `*Vector` is the start of a vector.

For converting a `*Network` piece into an igraph graph, glue it together with the `*Vertices`, `*Edges` and/or `*Arcs` pieces that come right after it, and then call `read.graph(..., format="pajek")` via a `textConnection()`. This way you don't need to create temporary files.

The `*Partition` and `*Vector` pieces are simple, just convert them to R vectors, using `scan()` and `textConnection()`.

I haven't tried all this, but I think it is not too difficult and should work fine. Tell me if you have any difficulties.

Also, Pajek file formats are poorly documented, so I might be wrong, there might be other piece types, etc.

You may also consider adding a bug report at the [igraph bug tracker](http://bugs.launchpad.net/igraph) to request this feature.

Comment: I have submitted a bug report for this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/igraph/+bug/1046133